# Is it safe to run OpenJDK images like Eclipse Temurin as root?

Tags: docker, adoptopenjdk, eclipse-temurin

I noticed that the examples for running the [Eclipse Temurin Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin) run the images as root and not as non-root user.

I thought it always would be better to run Docker images as non-root user?

Is it safe to run the Temurin images as root? (For example in a Azure K8s cluster?)

If not, which user should I use? Uid 65534 (nobody)? Or should I create a new user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that using the user **nobody** with uid **65534** works quite fine.

Now my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

RUN mkdir /home/nobody
WORKDIR /home/nobody

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

USER 65534

...
```